# Subscribe to chunked string data from Node using Angular observables for displaying it as soon as chunks get delivered

Tags: node.js, angular, express, observable, chunked

**Background**:
Angular recommends observables for app development - they are different from Promises because promises complete on a resolution or a rejection (one event) whilst observables can handle a stream of data (multiple events). My question is not about choosing one over the other, it is about reading a stream of data from NodeJS.

Digging deeper in observable
we see observable reading from stream of events, stream of data generated on client-side (form array, at a setInterval) etc.
My question is about observables (publisher - subscriber model) being used to subscribe to a nodeJS/expressJS backend, which will be the publisher here - which is sending simple res.write at a fixed interval.

**What I tried and What happened...**
when we use observable with this stream of string data being generated, the results are only displayed once the backend completes... the observable call is left hanging...

**What I'd like to happen?**
using Angular and observables, what will be the way to subscribe to this data and show it (on client-side) as and when it is generated (at server-side)

**server-side code using NodeJS / Express JS**

```js
app.get('/obs/responseWriteNEW', cors(), function(req, res) {
  var completedWrite = false;
  try {

    var j = 0;
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'text',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS, POST, GET',
      'Access-Control-Max-Age': 2592000, // 30 days
    };
    res.writeHead(200, headers);

    var i = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
      if (i < 100) {
        var myObj = {
          responseWriteNEW: i
        };
        var myStr = JSON.stringify(myObj);
        console.log(myStr);
        res.write(myStr);
        i++;
      } else {
        res.end();
      }
    }, 250);

  } catch (expp) {
    console.log(expp);
  }

});
```

client-side code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-44sess

**using vanilla-JS**, we got first chunk of data printed after the length of the streamed data went over a 1030.

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(ev) {  console.log(ev.target.responseText); $("#ajaxLog").append(ev.target.responseText); });
xhr.open("GET", 'http://localhost:2025/obs/responseWriteNEW');
xhr.send();
```

Comment: You will need websockets in order to make push notifications from your back-end to your front-end. Otherwise, you will need to make a request with `setInterval`, but you won't have control on your requests (for instance, you will make 1000 requests, while your data changed only once or twice).

Comment: Thanks @trichetriche, setInterval is like running the request iteratively, which is not efficient as you pointed out... I and people in my team were wondering if a solution other than webSockets existed... and wanted to make this question part of sO so that other people can benefit.

Comment: Well [google can help too](https://www.google.fr/search?q=alternative+to+websockets&rlz=1C1GCEU_frFR819FR820&oq=alternative+to+websockets&aqs=chrome..69i57.3783j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) !